# Can i connect a dc power supply rated 20v,6 A to a system which needs a power supply of 8-32v and 1.5A?

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply

Can i connect a dc power supply rated 20v,6 A to a system which needs a power supply of 8-32v and 1.5A? My  concern is about current. Will my system only consume max of 1.5A from supply instead of 6A?

Comment: Yes you can. Have a look at: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings/34746#34746

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  Generally, if the voltage is within the load rating, then the load will draw the current that it requires.  The current rating is - most often - the maximum amount of current that the PSU will supply at rated voltage.

Generally, you want to specify a PSU with a current rating that is somewhat higher than your maximum expected so that the PSU is not operating in a continually stressed condition.

Comment: -1 because your answer adds nothing new. I know it feels unfair, but these questions are so annoyingly repetitive (and also off-topic, since the OP wants to **use** a power supply, not to **design** one), that I feel answering them should be discouraged.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can as pointed out in the comments.

Two things

1. **You have to supply the voltage what the load requires** which in your case is 8-32V and your DC power supply is 20V which is in the required range of the load.
2. The next thing to watch out is the current which the power supply can provide you and the current which the load requires.Thing to remember is that **the power supply current rating should be more than what the load asks for**. Your load requires a current of 1.5A and therefore your supply should be able to supply this current and it would certainly do in this case since the maximum current which your DC power supply can provide is 6A. **Also your system would consume only what it needs** not more than that which in your case is 1.5A.

If the current rating of your power supply is less than the required current by the load then the load will not work properly(or may not even work) with this supply.

Comment: Yes @Dmitry Grigoryev you are right but this was not marked as a duplicate atleast when I wrote my answer. Also this looks like a basic question and yeah there should be some research OP should have done. yes I should also see this.